# can't import design in flutter app using api

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, photoshop

I want to develop an invitation card maker app in flutter so the issue is that I don't know what kind of data I will need to import from the backend to make my cards editable. i have designed cards in photoshop but I don't know how to make them editable in a mobile app. if anyone has a suggestion please give me your suggestions

Comment: Firstly, you should learn the flutter framework for how to make

Comment: Hi i can code in flutter but how i can import text and bg in same place as i have done in photoshop that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to be able to help you.

In those cases you do the following:

1. Receive image to edit.
2. Use external library made to edit photos (https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro)
3. Send edited image to the backend and replace the old one.

Comment: I would not recommend this package, since it does not support null safety, which is default with Flutter.

Comment: So the issue i like i want to import template from backend which are designed in psd and i can supply png, jpg or pdf. BUT to edit text on the cards like suppos i want to edit wedding venu on card i need text editable so i don't know how to import text seprately and backhround.

i can import bg but as thubnail i will need to show texts as well on actual editable card so how i can place text in perfect position when user open the card to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I am very happy that I finally found the solution.

So we have to first import the background image from API and load text data on it then we can use flutter packages to edit those texts.

But there is one thing you need to do before you import designs to the mobile app. You will need to have a perfect pixel size of font and background otherwise it will be overlapped.

I have images with dimensions of 3000*5000 so I have used aspect ratio for the responsiveness in every device.

And I have used Figma to design cards so we can get all CSS very fast for every line of text and then I am converting it to JSON using CSS to js converter and js to JSON converters.